# why to use Classes and styles in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I want to know that why does some code uses classes and styles in vue.js

Can anyone will let me know, well I do know about the usage when to apply CSS by classes and styles. Is this the same reason?

Comment: You should make your question a bit clearer, it's not easy to understand as of now. Please add some examples of what you mean, that makes it easier! :)

Comment: I wanted to know that why do we use classes and styles in tags in the files. For example:---                                                                                              <ul class="todo-list">
      <li v-for="todo in filteredTodos"
        class="todo"
        :key="todo.id"
        :class="{ completed: todo.completed, editing: todo == editedTodo }">

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to understand the purpose of class in Vue. You're right in saying that class can be used as a selector for styles. However in Vue, binding to class using the syntax

```
:class
```

allows you to apply dynamic styling which can be very useful for manipulating specific elements.

Taking the example you provided,

```
:class="{ completed: todo.completed, editing: todo == editedTodo }"
```

this is saying if todo.completed is truthy, then apply the 'completed' style or if the todo item equates to the value of editedTodo, then apply the 'editing' style.

Usually, these styles would be defined on the Vue component, but can also be changed in-line using the :style binding.

The Vue documentation lays this out very clearly:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Also, it should be noted that class and :class can co-exist on an element.